# Accessing unnested entries from JSON decoded into a plain array

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

```
$tempmoviename = "Battleship";
$omdburl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" . $tempmoviename;
$imdb_json = file_get_contents($omdburl);
$imdb_info = json_decode($imdb_json,true);
print ($imdb_info[0]->runtime[0]);
```

I can't get it to print the runtime of the movie. I can get it to print the actual website but not the information I need from the website.

In addition to that if I remove `true`

> > json_decode($imdb_json,true);

I get this error.

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

How do I write this so it grabs the data from an array correctly? I also need to swap spaces and dashes in titles like `Black Sheep`, `Black_Sheep` to `Black%20Sheep`?

Comment: Please post an example of the JSON returned in `$imdb_json` and decoded to `$imdb_info`.  Certainly if you remove the second param and continue trying to do `$imdb_info[0]` with an array index on an object it will complain.

Comment: You'll want to look at `htmlspecialchars()` for your secondary requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this... Since you are converting the JSON to array (by passing **true** in the `json_decode()`), You need to access it like an array.

```
<?php
$tempmoviename = "Battleship";
$omdburl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" . $tempmoviename;
$imdb_json = file_get_contents($omdburl);
$imdb_info = json_decode($imdb_json,true);

echo $imdb_info['Runtime']; //"prints" 131 min
```

Comment: Thank you. That does work.

Now how do I get it to pull a movie name from an array?

Comment: thanks everyone. Let me look into htmlspecialchars() and maybe preg_replace()